# Ant : find the last folder in a folder

Tags: ant

I have a folder path stored in the property `nightly.basepath` (here the value would be `/path/to/my/nightly`) :

```
/path/to/my/nightly
  |- build_20100310
  |- build_20100311
  |- build_20100312
```

I want to get the folder of the lastly generated build in the `nightly.basepath` folder, and store the path to this last folder in the `nightly.last` property. (So here, the value of `nightly.last` should be `/path/to/my/nightly/build_20100312`.)

Assume the alphabetical order reflects chronological order.

What is the easiest way to do that in Ant ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the [ant-contrib TimestampSelector](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/timestampselector.html).  I haven't used that particular task but I have used other ones in ant-contrib and haven't had any issues with them.